# Laravel - while migrate:refresh shows Key column 'asset_management_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. Recently I cloned sample project from github. I wanna develope the project. when I migrate by `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

It shows:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'asset_management_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `assets` add index ndx_AssetMgtID(`asset_management_id`))  
[PDOException]                                                                             

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'asset_management_id' doesn't exist in table
```

Comment: Link to the github repo project? Need to see the database migrations to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @EricMakesStuff: Oops!! thats in bitbucket :(

Comment: Look in `database/migrations`. Either the table definition of the `assets` table needs `$table->integer('asset_management_id');`, or the code that is trying to create an index has the wrong column name.